# iPhone app submitted with developer certificate

Tags: iphone, app-store, certificate, app-store-connect

I've just accidentially submitted an update for my app via `organizer` -> `distribute`, not noticing that my build settings still had the developer certificate set instead of the distribution certificate.

will the update still work on the users devices, or will it fail to install? I did not find any option to reset the submitted app, so I will probably have to wait until its published. Or will it even be rejected for not beeing signed with a distribution certificate?

Comment: You should be able to reject your binary via the iTunes connect site.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, eventually found it under `binary details`, NOT in the usual place where e.g. the "ready to upload binary" button is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

App Store will likely reject if you have the wrong certificate. Send Connect an email and explain, they're usually pretty helpful.